# Apache 400 Bad Request

Tags: apache, mvc, cookie, iis

Имеется такая ситуация: решили перевести сайт на `ClaimsBased` и все вроде бы ничего, кроме одной проблемы, которая появилась. Для авторизации пользователей использую `Thinktecture`, там все отрабатывает хорошо.

Но только работает все хорошо до того момента, пока веб-сайт не становится доступен извне. То есть, пока сайт крутится только в пределах сервера - все работает, как только я перевожу сайт в другое состояние (можно обратиться по адресу сайта) так и валится следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил немного [изменить файл конфигурации](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="300000000" maxQueryString="2097151">
          <headerLimits>
            <add header="Content-type" sizeLimit="10000"/>
          </headerLimits>
        </requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Задал большой лимит `headerLimits` и не помогло, та же проблема.
Даже нашел вот эту статью в интернете ["HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request Header too long)" error in Internet Information Services (IIS)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2020943)
Увеличил в реестре сервера `MaxFieldLength` и `MaxRequestBytes`, но правда  ***сервер не перезагрузил*** так как нет возможности перегрузить – *Production*.

Какие варианты решения данной проблемы подскажете? Сервер перегрузить не могу (склоняюсь к тому, что изменения в реестре не применятся до перезагрузки).

Comment: А почему бы не перезагрузить службу, если она не работает?

Comment: @ilyaplot, какую именно службу?

Comment: Службу IIS перезапустить, без перезагрузки сервера целиком

Comment: @ilyaplot, такая возможность появится только в среду, когда у нас запланированные регламентные работы...

Comment: Золотое правило - **никогда не вести разработку сразу на production**. Тем более IIS в целях разработки можно установить и на десктопной версии Windows. В Вашем случае лично я вижу два варианта. Первый - перенеси всё на отдельный сервер/ПК, там всё отладить и потом выложить на рабочий сервер. Второй - дожидаться "технологического окна". Но, при этом, подозреваю, работа будет стоять. Как-то так...

Comment: @Streletz, первым делом я развернул все на тестовом сервере, как только все заработало - развернул на продакшн сервере рядом с основным проектом без доступа из внешки. После того, как на продакшне заработало - начал настройку, чтобы полностью имитировать продакшн версию. Но получил данную ошибку, которую я описал. Разработка начинается в Development-версии, затем переходит в Test-версию, после этого на PreProduction-версию, а только уж потом на Production. Суть проблемы я описал, я не первый год работаю разработчиком, спасибо за советы, но по большей степени я придерживаюсь некоторых правил :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov, в том то и дело, что на production имеет смысл выкладывать только тогда когда всё уже полностью готово, а не тогда когда "всё заработало". Работать может, скажем так, по-разному. В Вашем случае production сервер частично используется в качестве тестового. Не хочу никого обидеть. Однако тот, кто организовал процесс разработки таким образом, сам себе злобный Буратино. Главная проблема здесь не в сервере. Увы...

Comment: @DenisBubnov, я тоже в профессии не первый год и поэтому знаю что и о чём говорю. По Вашему вопросу я уже высказал свои предложения и, к сожалению, пока добавить мне нечего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблем решена! Открыл сайт в браузере Mozilla и увидел, что размер `cookie` - 8.53 KB. Благодаря ответу: [Apache default limit is 8KB, in IIS it's 16K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/686243/5275890). Узнал о том, что у Apache размер `cookie` по умолчанию 8 KB.

Увеличил размер `cookie` до 12 KB и все заработало.

Comment: Однако, размер кукис... не первый год говорите работаете?

Comment: @AK, так вышло, что проект в срочном порядке перевели на меня и пришлось разбираться. Пока он работал на Development-версии - все было хорошо, перевели на Test - тоже все работало, даже на Pre-Production все работало хорошо. Но после того, как сайт положили на внешку - работать перестало. А все из-за того, что шлюз, через который идет трафик наружу - оборачивает пакеты дополнительным слоем безопасности и размер куки начинает переваливать за 8КБ. Вот такая забавная ситуация получилась. Да, кстати, из cookie убрали лишнее, теперь все хорошо, а ограничение вернули до 8КБ.